# Show/hide a record based on condition inside ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below are my records :

```
$scope.currentSelection = "Admin";

$scope.records = [
     { id: 'Employee', params:[]},
     { id: 'Skills', params:[]},
     { id: 'Payroll', params:[]},
     { id: 'Appraisal', params:[]},
     { id : 'Statistics',params:[]}
];
```

Now if $scope.currentSelection is admin then I want to show all items with `statistics(Employee,Skills,Payroll,Appraisal,Statistics)` else I don't want to show Statistics rest other items (Employee,Skills,Payroll,Appraisal) if $scope.currentSelection is Guest or Employee.

But the problem is when currentSelection is Admin then others items are not showing up except statistics.

Note: I don't want to use a filter for this.

But the problem

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
     $scope.currentSelection = "Admin";
     $scope.records = [
          { id: 'Employee', params:[]},
          { id: 'Skills', params:[]},
          { id: 'Payroll', params:[]},
          { id: 'Appraisal', params:[]},
          { id : 'Statistics',params:[]}
     ];
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
     <li ng-repeat="item in records">
         <div ng-show="currentSelection=='Admin' && item.id=='Statistics'">{{item.id}}
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Tushar But this is what i have already tried in my code so if you run my code then you will see only statistics is showing up and not other items(Employee,skills etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check is wrong,

**1)** It should be `ng-show="currentSelection=='Admin'` if you want to show every list items.

**2)** It should be `ng-show="currentSelection=='Guest ' ||currentSelection=='Employee' && item.id!=='Statistics'"` if you want to show every list items except statistics.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.currentSelection = "Admin";

 $scope.records = [
{ id: 'Employee', params:[]},
{ id: 'Skills', params:[]},
{ id: 'Payroll', params:[]},
{ id: 'Appraisal', params:[]},
{ id : 'Statistics',params:[]}
];

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
<ul ng-show="currentSelection=='Admin'">
    <li ng-repeat="item in records">
        {{item.id}}
    </li>
</ul>
<ul ng-show="currentSelection=='Guest' || currentSelection=='Employee'">
     <li ng-repeat="item in records" ng-if="item.id!=='Statistics'">
         {{item.id}}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually i want to place this condition on my li tag instead of div tag

Comment: You can't have two checks that easily on li since ng-repeat is defined on it

Comment: @Learning What you can do in that case create two ng-repeats with two different conditions based on currentSelection wrapping the parent element of li(ul)

Comment: Can you please show that part(having 2 ng repeat with 2 conditions) ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Sure will do :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to Change your show condition `currentSelection === 'Admin' && item.id === 'Statistics'` to `currentSelection === 'Admin' && item.id !== 'Statistics'`.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.currentSelection = "Non";

 $scope.records = [ { id: 'Employee', params:[]},
                    { id: 'Skills', params:[]},
                    { id: 'Payroll', params:[]},
                    { id: 'Appraisal', params:[]},
                    { id : 'Statistics',params:[]}];

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


 <ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div ng-if="currentSelection === 'Admin'">
    <li ng-repeat="item in records">
       <div>{{item.id}}</div>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="currentSelection !== 'Admin'">
  <li ng-repeat="item in records" ng-show="item.id !== 'Statistics'">
       <div>{{item.id}}</div>
  </li>
  </div>  
</ul>
```

Comment: When currentselection is admin then i want to show statistics also which is not displaying right now in your case

Comment: Thank you for appreciating our efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put a check on li tag itself. no need of extra div to put check. This will remove blank li bulltes.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.currentSelection = "Admin";

 $scope.records = [
{ id: 'Employee', params:[]},
{ id: 'Skills', params:[]},
{ id: 'Payroll', params:[]},
{ id: 'Appraisal', params:[]},
{ id : 'Statistics',params:[]}
];

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


 <ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
     <li ng-repeat="item in records" ng-if="currentSelection=='Admin' && item.id!=='Statistics'">
         <div >{{item.id}}
          </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When currentSelection is admin then i want to show statistics also which is not displaying right now if i use your code

Comment: I dont know what is difficlulty you facing to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-if` instance of `ng-show`

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.currentSelection = "Admin";

 $scope.records = [
{ id: 'Employee', params:[]},
{ id: 'Skills', params:[]},
{ id: 'Payroll', params:[]},
{ id: 'Appraisal', params:[]},
{ id : 'Statistics',params:[]}
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController"> 
 <ul  ng-repeat="item in records">
     <li ng-if="currentSelection === 'Admin' && item.id!=='Statistics'">
         <div>{{item.id}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When currentSelection is admin then i want to show statistics also which is not displaying right now if i use your code